# Searchable array inside a sheet gets called 6+ times on presenting sheet, even when typing on searchbar, array gets called 6+ times

Tags: arrays, swiftui, camera, searchable

So I'we been stuck on this for a few days and any feedback is very much appreciated!

I have a post option inside a custom camera view which once pressed, presents a sheet with a searchable bar. Problem is, once the post sheet is presented, array for searchable gets called 6+ times. Even when typing on the search bar, each keystroke results in the array getting loaded 6+ times.

I'm thinking loading this sheet whilst inside the camera is causing this sheet to load multiple times or perhaps it's something else. If anyone has experience dealing with this, any input?

Even when dismissing this sheet, on dismiss this array gets called 6+ times :(

(End goal is to use a 3rd party search api to fill the search result, this api gets called hundreds of times per keystroke)

```
  private var posts: [Post] {
    print("Array requested")
    return viewModel.searchText.isEmpty ? viewModel.posts() : viewModel.filteredPost()
}
            VStack{
                ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(posts) { post in
                      
                            PostCell(post: post)
                                .padding(.leading)

                       
                    }
                    
                }
                .searchable(text: $viewModel.searchText, placement: .sidebar, prompt: "Who/What is in this photo?"){
                    ForEach(posts, id: \.self) { result in
                        searchCompletion(result)
                    }
                }
            }
           
        }
```

Comment: Why have a computed property in your view that only deals with view model properties, why not have that functionality inside the view model?

Comment: I could, I did it like that initially as I declared searchtext in the view

Comment: So I moved the posts arrayto the view model, and called it from the view when the value of search text changes, it works! not elegant and not how its supposed to be implemented ( searchable) from what Ive read online. Anyways it works for now. array gets refreshed once. THANKS!

Comment: If you have a view model you might as well use it fully but if not then yes everything can be handled in the view. I suspect